# Extracting data from a clob field in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to extract data from a text field which has large paragraphs, I have tried using dbms_lob.substr(col,3992) but it seems to be truncating the data.

How can I extract the complete clob field for each row so I can export to excel?

Comment: if your want the complete clob field, then why are you trying to `substr` it ? just fetch the whole field instead

Comment: Depends on your client, and especially the driver, whether this is supported. Microsoft's Oracle driver, I think, doesn't support clobs very well. substr will get a small part of the clob (up to 4000 characters), and return it as a varchar2 value, which *is* supported.

Comment: I think my challenge is with exporting to excel.

Comment: OK, then can you please explain us how you are exporting to Excel ?

Comment: I guess the usual way, select, right click and export to excel, but the clob column data is cut off.

Comment: "right click and export to excel" is not helpful if you don't tell us which application you are using.

Comment: I am using toad, I have tried pl/sql developer as well but I am unable to export the entire data in the clob field.